# Symfony FOSRestBundle API - receives empty JSON Request body

Tags: php, json, api, symfony

I'm trying to build Symfony API with the bundle, but every request that I sent has empty body.

Controller:

```
class IndexController extends AbstractFOSRestController
{
    /**
     * @Rest\Post("/api/test", methods={"POST"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @return View
     */
    public function testError(
        Request $request
    ) : View {

        $requestData = $request->request->all(); // problem: requestData is []

        return View::create()
            ->setStatusCode(200)
            ->setFormat("json")
            ->setData(["data" => $requestData, "status" => "ok"]);
    }
}
```

I am sending this request from CURL:

```
curl -d '{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://localhost:8000/api/test
```

I've also tried sending it with Postman. I receive this response:

```
{"data":[],"status":"ok"}
```

Here is my fos_rest.yaml file:

```
fos_rest:
    view:
        view_response_listener: true
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: ^/api, prefer_extension: true, fallback_format: json, priorities: [ json, html ] }
            - { path: ^/, prefer_extension: true, fallback_format: json, priorities: [ html, json ] }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you forgot about proper serializer, which is mostly required.
Here is my config, should help you with it:

```
fos_rest:
    serializer:
        serialize_null: true
    body_listener:
        enabled: true
        throw_exception_on_unsupported_content_type:  true
        decoders:
            json: fos_rest.decoder.json
    format_listener:
        rules:
            - { path: '^/api', priorities: ['json'], fallback_format: json, prefer_extension: false }
            - { path: '^/', priorities: ['html', '*/*'], fallback_format: html, prefer_extension: true }
    param_fetcher_listener: force
    view:
        view_response_listener: 'force'
        formats:
            json: true
    allowed_methods_listener: true
services:
    fos_rest.decoder.json:
        class: FOS\RestBundle\Decoder\JsonDecoder
        public: true
```

---

Manual

[Symfony: Setting up the bundle, part B](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/1-setting_up_the_bundle.html#b-enable-a-serializer)

Comment: Because of something going on elsewhere allow me to make you aware of the pattern of spam which is camouflaged as thank-you non-answers. They need flagging as spam without any other action.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: One way to fix it is the accepted answer, the other is the below code

```
$requestData = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

return View::create()
        ->setStatusCode(200)
        ->setFormat("json")
        ->setData(["data" => $requestData, "status" => "ok"]);
```